# How does one "implicitly export an entire module"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

The following is [a section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_single_export_from_a_module) from MDN's reference on the JavaScript `import` statement (with added emphasis):

> #### Import a single export from a module
>
> Given an object or value named `myExport` which has been exported from the module `my-module` either ***implicitly (because the entire module is exported)*** or explicitly (using the [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) statement), this inserts `myExport` into the current scope.
>
> ```
> import {myExport} from '/modules/my-module.js';
> ```

I know what it means for an object or value to have been exported from a module *explicitly* (using the `export` statement), but how can they be exported *implicitly* (impliedly *without* using an `export` statement)?  What does it mean for an "entire module" to be exported?

Comment: `exports.variableName = 1` I think is the syntax. https://www.webreflection.co.uk/blog/2015/11/30/how-to-export-javascript-modules But i am not 100%, i'd be keen to know more about this subject.

Comment: @FrancisLeigh: That's CommonJS modules, not ES6.

Comment: There is no ES6 export without an `export` statement, but it might not need to explicitly name the export in case of a re-export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the wording on this statement is somewhat confusing, assuming I understand it correctly. I *think* what they mean by "explicitly" would be explicitly *named*, e.g.

```
export { foo };
// or others
export var foo;
export function foo(){}
export class foo {}
export { foo } from "./foo.js";
```

whereas *implicitly* would be one that is not explicitly named, like

```
export * from "./foo.js";
```

where then doing

```
import { foo } from "./mod.js";
```

would work as long as `mod` is re-exporting `foo` from the `foo.js` file.

Comment: Yes, this is the only sensible explanation.

Comment: You're probably right—but I had dismissed this thought as neither "the entire" of `mod` (which only re-exports `foo`'s exports) nor "the entire" of `foo` (which only exports whatever it explicitly exports) are actually exported; if correct, the statement "because the entire module is exported" should really read "because some module is fully re-exported using the `export * from` statement" or similar.

Comment: Yeah totally agree.

Comment: I notice that MDN has at some point been updated to confirm that this was indeed the intent, although they're still using the same confusing language.

Answer (score -1):

lets make it this way

1. Given an object or value named myExport which has been exported implicitly (because the entire module is exported) from a module

or

2. Given an object or value named myExport which has been exported explicitly (using the export statement) from a module

so i can export an object or func like this

```
// ./modules/my-module.js
export default UserApi = {
  myExport: function() {
   console.log(please make api call)
  }
}


// ./otherfile.js
import {myExport} from '/modules/my-module.js';
```

i never explicitly export `myExport` but you can import `myExport` without importing `UserApi` which i explicitly export

Comment: SyntaxError: The requested module '/modules/my-module.js' does not provide an export named 'myExport'